# How to autoexecute or calculate own written Excel vba public functions in defined cells

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a public function in VBA which make a `HTTP-request` to a Website and returns back a double value.

I use the function in 5 cells. When i open the `Excel-File` the cells don't update automatically.

How to setup Excel to execute the SelfMade public functions in some cells?

I have tested the following VBA statements but nothing works.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
'Application.CalculateFull
'Application.CalculateFullRebuild
'Worksheets("Aktie").Activate
'Range("J3:J6").Calculate
'ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
'Range("J3:J6").Select

'Worksheets("Aktie").Range("J3:J6").Calculate

End Sub
```

What i am doing wrong?

Which settings i have to make?

Where to put he VBA code to autoExecute it when open the XLS?

Comment: Try to add "Application.Volatile" on top of your function, it should do what you want.

Comment: If CalculateFullRebuild does not work something else is wrong. Try calling the finction from a sub in vba, see what it returns.

Comment: those statements are all `comments`. you do not have any executable statements in your sub

Comment: Application.volatile dont work in my case. Maybe there is something other wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is:
i have had the code in the wrong Object/module.
i putted it in Microsoft Excel Objects \ This Workbook
and Worksheet5 (Aktie).
Before i had it in Module \ modul 1 where i have the public functions too.